# gnome apps think there is no network

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, netplan

I had to reconfigure my machine network configuration from dhcp to static IP by manually editing netplan config. Apparently, there is some GNOME related configuration leftover, because several applications like :

1. software updater
2. `deja-dup` backup complain that there is no network and refuse to work.

Applications like `ssh`, `firefox`, `chromium`, etc work without any problem.
How can I fix that?

It is a fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, the configuration of the network is normally delegated to Network Manager by netplan.  Netplan itself does not interface with the GNOME network apis.  If you have changed your netplan config to use the networkd backend instead of the `NetworkManager` backend, then Network Manager will see the network as unmanaged and be unable to report online status to applications.

For best desktop integration, you should continue to use the 'NetworkManager` backend to netplan.  You can configure your static network directly in the netplan config, or you can configure it in Network Manager.